# Dual OS setup on a bootable flash drive?

Tags: dual-boot

I know how to create a bootable flash drive with an operating system, but i would like both ubuntu 12.04 and linux mint 16 cinnamon to be bootable from one flash drive. Is this possible, and if so how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Partition your hard drive with something like Gparted, or any hard drive editor, into FAT32, as you can usually only install OS onto FAT32. When you partition something, it basically splits it into to seperate sections for putting files in.
2. Use http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net UNetbootin to install an OS onto usb drive. (Make sure you choose the right spot (partition) for installation. It's pretty straightforward once you download it, you just open it, choose the distro you want, and choose the usb device you want to install it to. Note the options will be like disk2s1, to find which one is which (I've only done this on mac), you need to type in "diskutil list", it'll tell you the normal name of the drive, and the numbered name like disk1s2. Usually the thing you put on a usb drive is a live boot, which you can boot it from.
3. That's basically it, unless you need a bootloader, like REfind http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/.

Tips

-Please know that you can only run it from the usb, it won't save anything. To make it save, you have to install an OS from another storage device. For example, I could install Ubuntu onto my computer by first making a partitioned spot for the installation of Ubuntu (usually EXT4 format) on your computer and then loading up the thing you installed with the above guides and using the installer to install to your computer partition
-please keep in mind this is my first answer I think, so I may have gotten stuff wrong.

Comment: With "pen drive linux", a program that makes usb drives bootable, you can make a persistant file so everything you save stays with you. Are you sayig theres no way to partitiin the flash drive and then create two persistant file folders, one for each os?

Comment: I was unaware you could save anything when booting without actually installing the OS, but I guess you could with that program, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though I will try the partition and then making a persistant file thia weekend

Comment: If you like my answer please set it as such. If you found a better method it would be helpful for future people if you posted what you've found.